# How do I update podcasts on my iPhone that are not listed in the iTunes directory?

Tags: iphone, itunes, podcasts, itunes-store

I listen to a number of podcasts that are not listed in the iTunes directory (and never will be) -- is it possible to update these podcasts from the iPhone to get the latest episodes while I'm on-the-go?

Now, the one catch: I know I could use a separate app or mobile web site to listen to the podcasts, but I'd like to be able to do this so that I can still use the built-in iPod software to listen to the podcasts.

If this is not currently possible, any idea if it is at least technically possible to build an app with the new SDK that would allow for this?

**Update:**

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625625/access-to-iphone-music-library/625686#625686) over on StackOverflow describing the SDK's Music Library Access API, and it looks like my request can not be accomplished via a separate app, either.

Comment: Whoops, I marked this as "community wiki" -- how do I undo that?

Comment: arathron: unforatunately you can't (not even a moderator can). http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6821/ability-to-undo-the-community-wiki

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iPod player on iPhones currently can only download new Podcasts from via iTunes/App Store.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the podcast is distributed with an RSS feed with enclosure tags, you can subscribe to it by using 'Advanced->Subscribe to Podacst' menu in iTunes.

Comment: Sure, I'm subscribed to the podcasts in iTunes already, and they sync to the iPhone. My question is if and how I can update them *from the iPhone*. It seems as though this is only possible for iTMS podcasts, but I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

[RSS Player](http://rssplayer.blogspot.com/) will let you download / stream any podcast wirelessly.  It is normally $0.99 on [iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=302006628&mt=8).

Comment: Right, but as I note above, the "catch" in my question is, I'd like to be able to still use the iPod app on the phone to listen to the updated podcast episodes.